# Open/close dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I started to build clicks manner such that there will be like a box up. it can in no way get to work at all!. so is it like when you create an account and click "opret_ok" then the close box/dialog by itself.

```
<a href="#" id="contactUs">Oppen</a>                   
    <div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
       <form action="#" method="post" name="opret_nyheder">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Navn</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="navn" class="new"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email - Brugernavn</td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="email_indhold" class="new"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="opret_ok" value="Opret Bruger" class="new"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST["opret_ok"]))
            {
                $opret_bruger = $mebe->opret_bruger();
            }
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#contactUs").click(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I'll get nothing from jquery page about box or style. All I have here is what I show on the outside of the body, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click','input[name="opret_ok"]',function(){
   jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: okay thanks, Now should I also just have made ​​so that I can open it :)

Comment: you can use `$('#dialog').dialog('open');`

Comment: I can in no way open dialog box at all. :(

Comment: When you want to open it ?

Comment: Yes thanks., I do not just add `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` or did you?

Comment: dont forget to write `http:` in your jquery link .. it should be . `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>‌`

Comment: i cant not oppe the dialog :(